# Global Macros in Code::Blocks

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am using Code::Blocks 10.05 over Windows 7. My doubt is about the menu item
           **Management->Symbols->Global macros**.

I have the following program called 1.c using the header file 1.h,

**1.c**

```
#include "1.h"
#define CONSTANT 4
#define M() x*x
int x=CONSTANT,y=9;

int main()
{
  printf("\nAnswer 1 is %d\n",P());
  printf("\nAnswer 2 is %d\n",N(y));
}
```

**1.h**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N(x) x*x*x
#undef P()
#define P() x*x*x*x
```

But all the macros defined in the program are displayed as Preprocessor symbols and not as Global macros. Why is it so? How can we declare a macro as global such that it is shown in the Global macros menu of Code::Blocks?

The Preprocessor symbols list is shown below for reference,

```
# CONSTANT 4
# M:x*x
# N:x*x*x
# P:x*x*x*x
```

Thanking You in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with `global macros` vs `pre-processor symbols`?

Comment: There is a menu item for Global macros and another one for Preprocessor symbols in Code::Blocks Management->Symbols menu. But I too don't know which macro definition comes under Global macros.

Comment: I use only a derivate of C::B. I can set `Custom variables` in the Settings/Compiler menu, Custom variables tab. But everything you define in a header file or compilation unit is a pre-processor macro.

Comment: The global macros page holds things that are typically used as macros for project building. E.g there's a setting page for wx(Widgets) - this contains the folders that wxWidgets is found in. Similarly, SDL is defined here if installed (I imagine) as are settings in my copy of C::B for glut. If you wish to set global macros in the same way that you do when you `#define` something, then you can goto `Settings->Compiler:Global compiler settings-Compiler settings-#defines` (just leave off the `#define` but type otherwise as normal. e.g `UNICODE`, rather than `#define UNICODE`)

Comment: Please post it as an answer...